# How to override static variables from inherited derived classes in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to have the the static implementation of a static method use the derived class's value.  For example, in the simple example below, when I call `User.findById()` I want it to use the overridden tableName `User` when executing the implementation defined in the base class SqlModel.

How do I make sure that the base classes static tableName uses 'User' and is this the right way of essentially declaring an abstract static property?

```
class SqlModel {

    protected static tableName:string;

    protected _id:number;
    get id():number {
        return this._id;

    }

    constructor(){

    }

    public static findById(id:number) {
        return knex(tableName).where({id: id}).first();
    }

}

export class User extends SqlModel {

    static tableName = 'User';

    name:string;

    constructor(username){
        this.name = username;
    }
}
```

And I would get an error saying tablename is not defined, but if I say SqlModel.tableName then it doesn't use the derived classes table name

```
User.findById(1); //should call the knex query with the tablename 'User'
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `this.tableName`:

```
class SqlModel {
    protected static tableName: string;

    public static outputTableName() {
        console.log(this.tableName);
    }
}

class User extends SqlModel {
    protected static tableName = 'User';
}

User.outputTableName(); // outputs "User"
```

Comment: does not work in typescript > 1.8 I believe. There exists workaround:
(this.constructor as any).tableName as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727307/referencing-class-without-name-to-use-different-static-method-in-subclasses-in-t

Comment: @Dominik the difference is that in this case the question is asking about a static method—`findById`—not an instance method.

Comment: The problem is static members are bound to the *class* and can not be referenced via an instance. `console.log(this.tableName);` does not work. `console.log(SqlModel.tableName)` works, but is not polymorphic. `console.log((this.constructor as any).tableName)` works and is polymorphic but not pretty.

Comment: @snarf take note that the method here is `static` and not an instance method. `this.constructor.tableName` would be `undefined` in a static method in this scenario and `this.tableName` would work. (Edit: maybe I misunderstood and you are responding to the above comments? Anyway, use `this.constructor.tableName` for instance methods and `this.tableName` in static ones)

Comment: My mistake. I did not read closely enough. I thought OP was accessing the static property from an instance method.

Answer (score 9):

I managed to get the static like this:

```
(<typeof SqlModel> this.constructor).tableName
```

Comment: Note that this is what you would do in an instance method and not a static method (question was about a static method, but this is useful information anyways).