# Referencing class without name to use different static method in subclasses in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript1.8

In ES6, you can reference static methods via `this.constructor`:

```
class MainClass {
  static info() {
    return "This is some information";
  }
  constructor() {
    this.info = this.constructor.info(); // Allows subclass to define different '.info()' method.
  }
}

class ChildClass extends MainClass {
  static info() {
    return "This information is from the child";
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in TypeScript? I want to be able to override the super class's static method and use it from the subclass without redefining the reference in an instance method. Right now, the only way I know how to access a static method in TypeScript uses the class name.

```
MainClass.info();
```

But if I do that, the subclass will continue to use `MainClass.info();` rather than it's own `.info()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout this typescript code:

```
class MainClass {
  static info() {
    return "This is some information";
  }
  info: string;

  constructor() {
    this.info = (this.constructor as any).info(); // Allows subclass to define different '.info()' method.
  }
}

class ChildClass extends MainClass {
  static info() {
    return "This information is from the child";
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
```

If compilation target is ES6 this compiles to exaclty the code you gave above and works fine. It also works fine if it is compiled down to ES5.

Note that I used a `as any` hack to allow calling `.info()` on the `constructor` function.

Alternatively, you could overwrite the setting of `this.info` in each child class. This way you wouldn't need the hack.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Could you provide an example of what you mean by "overwrite the setting of `this.info`"? Does that use TypeScript's get/set methods in some way? I haven't used those much so I'm not familiar with the syntax.

Comment: ah, no, what I meant was to add a line to the `ChildClass` constructor like `this.info = ChildClass.info()` and then say in the `MainClass` `this.info = MainClass.info()` instead of using the `this.constructor` approach there. This _should_ work as well (I haven't tested it) and might be more predictable.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful answer. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 5):

How about this:

```
interface MainClassConstructor {
    new (): MainClass;
    info(): string;
}

class MainClass {
    static info() {
        return "This is some information";
    }

    private info: string;

    constructor() {
        this.info = (this.constructor as MainClassConstructor).info(); // Allows subclass to define different '.info()' method.
    }
}

class ChildClass extends MainClass {
    static info() {
        return "This information is from the child";
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MainClassConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%09new%20()%3A%20MainClass%3B%0D%0A%09info()%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MainClass%20%7B%0D%0A%09static%20info()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%22This%20is%20some%20information%22%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09private%20info%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09this.info%20%3D%20(this.constructor%20as%20MainClassConstructor).info()%3B%20%2F%2F%20Allows%20subclass%20to%20define%20different%20'.info()'%20method.%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ChildClass%20extends%20MainClass%20%7B%0D%0A%09static%20info()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%22This%20information%20is%20from%20the%20child%22%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09super()%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D))

---

#### Edit

You can also use `typeof MainClass` instead of the `MainClassConstructor` interface I added:

```
class MainClass {
    static info() {
        return "This is some information";
    }

    private info: string;

    constructor() {
        this.info = (this.constructor as typeof MainClass).info(); // Allows subclass to define different '.info()' method.
    }
}
```

In addition there's a discussion/suggestion of having `this.constructor` returning the right type here: [T.constructor should be of type T](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841).

Another option is to use method overriding:

```
class MainClass {
    private info: string;

    constructor() {
        this.info = this.getInfo();
    }

    protected getInfo(): string {
        return "This is some information";
    }
}

class ChildClass extends MainClass {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    protected getInfo(): string {
        return "This information is from the child";
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `as typeof MainClass` is a nice addition to provide accurate typing support without much extra code, thank you for that. Your third code block does not use static methods, but I believe you're trying to demonstrate something like @dpoetzsch suggested in his comment about overwriting setting the property. Is that right? (I tried to paste a playground link but it's too long for a comment)

Comment: In OO you usually avoid overriding static methods, the whole concept of static members/methods is not very OO.  In my last code block I set the `info` member just once in the parent class, but the value it gets from the `getInfo` method which you can then override in your subclasses.  I don't like changing the value that the parent has set in child classes, it's error prone. With this `getInfo` method there's just one place where the assignment happens.