# TypeScript: static properties and inheritance

Tags: inheritance, typescript, static, typescript1.8

I'm quite new to TypeScript (1.8) and I have a small issue with inheritance and static properties.

Please find below the test code I'm currently running:

```
class A {
    public static Items = {
        FOO: 'A'
    };

    public show() {
        alert(this.constructor.Items.FOO);
    }
} 

class B extends A {
    public static Items = {
        FOO: 'B'
    };
}

var a = new A();
var b = new B();

a.show(); // alert "A"
b.show(); // alert "B"
```

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20static%20Items%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09FOO%3A%20'A'%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20show()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09alert(this.constructor.Items.FOO)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20static%20Items%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09FOO%3A%20'B'%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0Avar%20b%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.show()%3B%20%2F%2F%20alert%20%22A%22%0D%0Ab.show()%3B%20%2F%2F%20alert%20%22B%22)

This code runs fine and the two alerts are shown as expected.

**BUT** the TypeScript compiler throws an error : `Property "Items" does not exist on type "Function"`

I understand the warning and it's totally right from a TypeScript point of view, but how can I achieve the same result while making the compiler happy?  `this.Items.FOO` obviously does not work and I didn't find a `self` equivalent or something like that...

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Notice that your `show` method won't work when you introduce an additional subclass that does *not* have a static `Items` property, e.g. `class C extends A {}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a similar question today: [Referencing class without name to use different static method in subclasses in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727307/referencing-class-without-name-to-use-different-static-method-in-subclasses-in-t).

There's a discussion/suggestion of having `this.constructor` returning the right type here: [T.constructor should be of type T](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841).

As for possible solutions for you for now:

Without static at all:

```
class A {
    public show() {
        alert(this.getItems().FOO);
    }

    protected getItems() {
        return {
            FOO: 'A'
        }
    };
}

class B extends A {
    protected getItems() {
        return {
            FOO: 'B'
        }
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20show()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09alert(this.getItems().FOO)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09protected%20getItems()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09FOO%3A%20'A'%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09protected%20getItems()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09return%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09FOO%3A%20'B'%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0Avar%20b%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.show()%3B%20%2F%2F%20alert%20%22A%22%0D%0Ab.show()%3B%20%2F%2F%20alert%20%22B%22))

Static with `typeof`:

```
class A {
    public static Items = {
        FOO: 'A'
    };

    public show() {
        alert((<typeof A | typeof B> this.constructor).Items.FOO);
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20static%20Items%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09FOO%3A%20'A'%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20show()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09alert((this.constructor%20as%20typeof%20A).Items.FOO)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20static%20Items%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09FOO%3A%20'B'%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0Avar%20b%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.show()%3B%20%2F%2F%20alert%20%22A%22%0D%0Ab.show()%3B%20%2F%2F%20alert%20%22B%22))

Static with constructor interface:

```
interface AConstructor {
    new (): A;
    Items: any;
}

class A {
    public static Items = {
        FOO: 'A'
    };

    public show() {
        alert((this.constructor as AConstructor).Items.FOO);
    }
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20AConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20()%3A%20A%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Items%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20static%20Items%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09FOO%3A%20'A'%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09public%20show()%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09alert((this.constructor%20as%20AConstructor).Items.FOO)%3B%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20static%20Items%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09FOO%3A%20'B'%0D%0A%09%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0D%0Avar%20b%20%3D%20new%20B()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.show()%3B%20%2F%2F%20alert%20%22A%22%0D%0Ab.show()%3B%20%2F%2F%20alert%20%22B%22))

Comment: `alert((<typeof A|typeof B>this.constructor).Items.FOO);` for your typeof solution, otherwise `B.Items -> B.ItemsRenamed` won't be caught.

Comment: @mk. thanks, i updated my answer, though i think that this solution isn't very useful when you have more than two classes. The first option (without the static) is better in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

> I understand the warning and it's totally right from a TypeScript point of view

Right - this is something like inheritance, but it doesn't and shouldn't generally work for your static properties. To get around this, disable typechecking using `any`:

```
alert((<any>this.constructor).Items.FOO);
```

This situation often occurs when converting old js code, but should be avoided when writing new TS code. If you want to do this correctly you would need to (as you are probably aware) implement and override a `getItems` or similar method in your two classes to return the corresponding `Items`, and call that method from `show`.