# Property 'propname' is a static member of type 'Class'

Tags: typescript

This code does not compile with typescript.
It says `Property 'say' is a static member of type 'Animal` on line 11 (last).

Could someone please explain why?

```
class Animal {
    static say: string;
}
class Dog extends Animal{
    static say = 'bark'
}
class Cat extends Animal{
    static say = 'meow'
}
const animals:Animal[] = [Dog, Cat]
animals.filter(e=>e.say ==='meow')
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: static properties and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732427/typescript-static-properties-and-inheritance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've narrowed the type on `animals` to be *instances* of those classes, not the classes themselves. Try this:

```
const animals: (typeof Animal)[] = [Dog, Cat];
```

or just leave off the type and let it be inferred;

Comment: Yes, and that annotation doesn't cause an error because those the instance type `Animal` is [empty](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely), and therefore any non-nullish type is assignable to it, including `typeof Dog` and `typeof Cat`.  Classes should always have instance properties of some sort to prevent this sort of accidental structural compatibility.